# Javascript shortage for (num>0)?num:0

Tags: javascript, sum, formula

Are there any way to write `(num>0)?num:0` even shorter in javascript?

The reason is `num` variable is not defined yet and needs to be calculated twice in the case above.

Using another words, a and b are known. I want to write `(a>b)?(a-b):0` even shorter. Is that possible in javascript? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean it has to be calculated twice?

Comment: My option is to add var num = a-b (which is not perfect) or to use a-b instead of num (calculated twice).

Comment: `Math.max(num, 0)` but note that it my actually be slower than the original version. Also, it behaves differently from the original expression if `num` is not a number. It is not clear why you need the answer to be "shorter" unless you're entering some sort of contest that counts source code size.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder OK, next time I will. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer after the edit:**:

I'd probably go ahead and do the subtraction, then do the test:

```
num = a - b;
if (num < 0) {
    num = 0;
}
```

But

```
num = a > b ? a - b : 0;
```

...seems totally fine as well.

Remember that optimizing before there's a problem ("premature optimization") is usually a waste of time. That's true generally, but it's *especially* true in JavaScript because different engines behave differently.

**Answer before the edit**:

No, I don't think there's a shorter way to write that.

> The reason is num variable is not defined yet and needs to be calculated twice in the case above.

If you mean that `num` is really a calculation, then cache that to a variable:

```
var num = /*...the calculation...*/;
var result = num > 0 ? num : 0;
```

---

Comment: `var num = Math.max(a-b, 0);`

Comment: @epascarello: :-) Shorter, but slower.

Comment: Well they did not ask for faster ;)

Comment: @epascarello: Indeed. :-)

Comment: I think they asked although didn't mention it:)

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
Math.max(num, 0)
```

If `num` is less then `0` this expression will return `0`, otherwise `num` itself.